# ExtJS5 Menu panel disappears when panel lose focus

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

when i run this code , it will generate a menu panel, but in ExtJS 5.1 the menu panel will disappears when once you click the menu item and then click anywhere else.

is that a ExtJS 5.1's bug ?

ExtJS 5.0 and ExtJS 4.x are work fine.

```js
Ext.application({
    name : 'Fiddle',

    launch : function() {
        var menu = Ext.create('Ext.menu.Menu',{
            floating : false,
            items : [{
    text : 'Service Info',
    itemId : 'service'
   },{
                 xtype: 'menuseparator'
             },{
    text : 'Project Info',
    itemId : 'project'
   }],
            renderTo  : Ext.getBody()
        })
    }
});
```

https://fiddle.sencha.com/?fiddle=jhb#fiddle/jhb

Comment: There seem at least 5 more configs in the newer documentation than in the old one so it could quite possibly be intended behaviour but would be odd that it changes backwards compatibility out of the box!

Old version http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/5.0.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.menu.Menu

New version http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.menu.Menu

Comment: I think this is a 5.1.0's bug , http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?296537-5.1.0-trouble-with-menus-disappearing , thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found this bug in Sencha Community Forums ,http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?296537-5.1.0-trouble-with-menus-disappearing 
but this fix are not included by release build(Ext JS 5.1.0.107)